# Ansible: Delete directories past a certain mdate depending if there are more than 3 subdirectories in directory

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have an ansible playbook that I need to add a task to. Essentially I have a directory that on each deploy adds another subdirectory. When there are more than 3 subdirectories I want to delete all of the older directories past the 3 most recent directories. I am having a very hard time trying to write a play for it. 
I first try to get all the subdirectories

`- name: Get all install artifacts
  find:
    paths: "{{ home_path }}/install/"
    file_type: directory
    recurse: no
  register: install_artifacts`

But after this I am trying to check if there are more than 3 items, and if so get the 3rd items modified date, and delete everything with a modified date earlier than this.

Answer (score 3):

```
- block:
    - name: Determine old directories
      set_fact:
        old_dirs: "{{ (install_artifacts.files|sort(attribute='mtime', reverse=True))[3:] }}"

    - name: Remove old directories
      file:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        state: absent
      with_items: "{{ old_dirs }}"
  when: install_artifacts.matched > 3
```

First of all, `install_artifacts.files|sort(attribute='mtime', reverse=True)` will sort the list of dicts by `mtime` in descending order. `[3:]` means removing the first 3 items from the list, which are the 3 most recent directories. So `old_dirs` now contains all the old directories.

Comment: there is only one small typo in the `when` line: `when: install_artifacts.matched > 3`